# Matplotlib bar plot with two different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

In a Dataframe column with 10 values, I am trying to create a bar plot with the first 5 being blue, and the remaining 5 red.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"x": range(10)})

In [4]: ax = df.iloc[:5].plot(kind="bar", color="blue")

In [5]: plt.show()

In [6]: df.iloc[5:].plot(kind="bar", color="grey", ax=ax)
Out[6]: <Axes: >

In [7]: ax.bar(df.index[5:].values, df.iloc[5:, 0].values, color="grey")
Out[7]: <BarContainer object of 5 artists>
```

[5] Shows the plot of the first 5 blue elements. I tried two ways of adding the second part, [6] and [7], but that was not successful. I tried using plt.show() which did not show anything. A final `ax.figure.savefig("fig.png")` shows a barplot of the last 5 elements in grey.

How do I get them into one figure?

I tried using the above code to generate the desired figure. Tried putting the same commands into a jupyter notebook yielding the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of what you want is unclear. Do you want to get something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 11)})
ax = df['x'].plot(kind='bar', color=['blue']*5+['red']*5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the desired output. I actually realize now what the problem was. I had a df with one column, so I used df.plot(). This makes the list elements in the color argument react to the different columns, so in this case displaying the same color for all values. So for my case, the solution was to select the exact column. Thanks!